# How Can I get Monthly Income, Expenditure, Net Income and display in django Template using a loop

Tags: python, django

I am working on a Django project with two models; Expenditure and Income. I want to get Total Income, Total Expenditure, and Net Income for each month displayed in a table. The Net Income should be Total Income minus (-) Total Expenditure. And here  I have these models (Income and Expenditure are same) are having the same properties as shown below.

```
class Income(models.Model):
      description = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
      category = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=CATEGORY_INCOME, null=True)
      staff = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
      amount = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=False)
      remarks = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True)
      date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, null=False)
      addedDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Here what I have tried in my views file:

```
def monthly_Income(request):
total_monthly_income = Income.objects.annotate(month=TruncMonth('date')).values('month').annotate(total_monthly_income=Sum('amount'))
total_monthly_expenses = Expenditure.objects.annotate(month=TruncMonth('date')).values('month').annotate(total_monthly_expenses=Sum('amount'))
net_monthly_income = total_monthly_income - total_monthly_expenses
context = {
    'total_monthly_income': total_monthly_income,
    'total_monthly_expenses':total_monthly_expenses,
'net_monthly_income':net_monthly_income'
}
```

In my django Template this is how  I am trying to display the results.

```
{% for income in total_monthly_income %}
{{ income.total_monthly_income | intcomma }}
{{ total_monthly_expenses }}
{{ net_monthly_income }}
 {% endfor %}
```

The problem here is that, I am able to get the total monthly income but not able to get the total monthly expenses and net income according to each month of the year.
Someone should kindly assist me get the right result accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

As I guessed you have query set for `total_monthly_income` and `total_monthly_expenses`. So I updated your function as following

**views changes:**

```
def monthly_Income(request):

    #Get Day of today from current date and time
    now = datetime.datetime.now()

    total_monthly_income = Income.objects.annotate(month=TruncMonth('date')).values('month').annotate(total_monthly_income=Sum('amount'))
    total_monthly_expenses = Expenditure.objects.annotate(month=TruncMonth('date')).values('month').annotate(total_monthly_expenses=Sum('amount'))
    income_expense = zip(total_monthly_income, total_monthly_expenses)
    
    net_monthly_income_list = []
    
    for income, expense in income_expense:
        net_monthly_income_list.append(income.get('total_monthly_income', 0) - expense.get('total_monthly_expenses', 0))
    
    income_list = zip(total_monthly_income, total_monthly_expenses, net_monthly_income_list)
    
    context = {
        'income_list': income_list
    }

    return render(request, 'cashier/view_income_monthly.html', context)
```

**Also required some modification in your template file as following:**

```
<tbody>
    {% for total_monthly_income, total_monthly_expenses, net_monthly_income in income_list %}
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">{{ forloop.counter }}</th>
            <td nowrap>{{ total_monthly_income.month }}</td>
            <td nowrap>{{ total_monthly_income.total_monthly_income | intcomma }}</td>
            <td >{{ total_monthly_expenses.total_monthly_expenses | intcomma }}</td>
            <td >{{ net_monthly_income | intcomma }}</td>
        
            <td nowrap>
                <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href="#">Edit</a>
                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" href="#">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}             
</tbody>
```

**Hopefully now it should work for you. :)**

Comment: @Sbil. Thanks for your answer but after running the script this is the error: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'QuerySet' and 'QuerySet' that appears in the browser.

Comment: what is the data type for `total_monthly_income, total_monthly_expenses, net_monthly_income`?

Comment: they are **PositiveIntegerField**. **total_monthly_income, and total_monthly_expenses** are variables holding the sum of **'amount' field** from those models and they are PositiveIntegerField (amount model field) while the net_monthly_income is a variable I am expecting to hold the calculation (the difference between them).

Comment: is it possible to print the data in your question?

Comment: Don't really understand what you mean but I want to print out the results of the calculation in my template

Comment: I mean, could you please add `print(total_monthly_income, total_monthly_expenses, net_monthly_income)` in `monthly_Income` this function and provide the printed output from that function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236405/discussion-between-apollos-and-sabil).

Comment: Please check my updated answer. It should work now

Comment: thanks for your edited answer but it is only outputting/displaying recently **added monthly income and expenditure net income** and not all the months in the models. Whereas I want a case where user has added his/her income and expenditure for Jan, Feb, March, April, May to December, the script should calculate their net income for all the months in those years

Comment: Check the updated one. It should work between date range

Comment: Thanks for your efforts in trying to help me. Your last edited code almost got everything right but the only problem is that the total monthly expenses has been interchanged and the net income results are displayed wrongly. For example: The first Total Monthly Expenses figure usually switches to the last one and the last Total Monthly Expenses goes to the next one up in the table thereby displaying wrong Net income for all of them.